# Sincronizar audios con HTML5 y Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Quiero unir dos audios en uno solo para sincronizarlos con HTML5 en el lado del cliente. He visto que se con Web Audio Api se pueden hacer multitud de cosas, pero no he sido capaz de encontrar como hacerlo.

Tengo el enlace a dos archivos de audio (.mp3, .wav...), lo que quiero es sincronizar estos dos archivos de audio, como si fueran una voz y una canción. No quiero unirlos uno detrás del otro, quiero sincronizarlos.

Me gustaría hacerlo todo en el lado del cliente utilizando HTML5, sin usar un servidor. ¿Es posible hacerlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es sincronizar los audios y que suenen a la vez, la idea sería que tu programa usara el evento `canplaythrough` e hiciese lo siguiente:

- Define una variable que servirá  como contador para los audios cargados.
- Crea los dos audios en la página **sin autoplay**.
- Pon un controlador del evento `canplaythrough` en los audios.
- Cuando termine de cargarse el audio se disparará el controlador, que hará:

  - Añadir +1 al contador de audios cargados.
  - ¿Se han cargado todos los audios?

    - Si sí, haz play de los audios a la vez.

¿Por qué usar el evento `canplaythrough` en lugar del `loadeddata` o `canplay`? El evento `canplaythrough` se lanza cuando se han cargado suficientes datos como para saber que se podrá tocar la melodía completa sin necesidad de hacer buffering. Algo que podría hacer que se desincronizaran los audios.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo comentado de dos audios diferentes (aunque bastante disonantes, lo siento) que suenan a la vez de forma sincronizada:

```js
// contador de audios cargados
var cargados = 0;

// controlador del evento canplaythrough
function sincronizarAudio() {
  // aumentamos el número de audios que se han cargado
  cargados++;
  
  // si se han cargado los dos audios que queremos sincronizar
  if (cargados == 2) {
    // le damos play a los dos
    audio1.play();
    audio2.play();
  }
}

// crea un elemento audio
var audio1 = document.createElement("audio");
// asigna la fuente del sonido
audio1.setAttribute("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg");
// opcional: especifica que se vean los controles
audio1.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
// añade el controlador del evento canplaythrough
audio1.oncanplaythrough = sincronizarAudio;
// añade el elemento al cuerpo de la página
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(audio1);

// lo mismo de arriba pero con otro audio/video
var audio2 = document.createElement("audio");
audio2.setAttribute("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg");
audio2.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
audio2.oncanplaythrough = sincronizarAudio;
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(audio2);
```

Si además quieres que se sincronicen cuando se haga pausa/play, lo que puedes hacer es añadir controladores  de eventos para `pause` y `play` que aplicarían el método `pause()` y  `play()` respectivamente a todos los audios sincronizados.

En el siguiente ejemplo he usado dos audios un poco más largos (aunque de diferente duración, lo que puede causar problemas) para que puedas ver como al hacer pausa/play en uno de ellos el otro también hace pausa/play.

```js
var cargados = 0;

function sincronizarAudio() {
  cargados++;

  if (cargados == 2) {
    audio1.play();
    audio2.play();
  }
}

function sincronizarPlay() {
  audio1.play();
  audio2.play();
}

function sincronizarPause() {
  audio1.pause();
  audio2.pause();
}

var audio1 = document.createElement("audio");
audio1.setAttribute("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg");
audio1.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
audio1.oncanplaythrough = sincronizarAudio;
audio1.onplay = sincronizarPlay;
audio1.onpause = sincronizarPause;
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(audio1);

var audio2 = document.createElement("audio");
audio2.setAttribute("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg");
audio2.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
audio2.oncanplaythrough = sincronizarAudio;
audio2.onplay = sincronizarPlay;
audio2.onpause = sincronizarPause;
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(audio2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo que es una pregunta de hace tiempo, pero definitivamente quien pase por aquí debería tomarse un minuto para revisar [Howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/) que permite acceder a las funciones de Web Audio Api y degradarlas a HTML5 audio en los navegadores más antiguos. Sincronizar audios es una tarea implementada en el core de howler, loop sin pausas, sprite audio, etc.

**Actualización:**
Me gustó la solución de Álvaro y me pregunté por cómo se mantiene la sincronía entre ambos audios a lo largo del tiempo, y con audios más largos. Así que generé este snippet para probar. Resulta una sincronización muy buena! Lamentablemente con la API de HTML5 no se puede poner un audio el `left` y otro en `right`, tampoco se pueden hacer `seamless loops` y la [Web Audio API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/)

```js
var cargados = 0;

function sincronizarAudio() {
  cargados++;

  if (cargados == 2) {
    audio1.play();
    audio2.play();
  }
}

function sincronizarPlay() {
  audio1.play();
  audio2.play();
}

function sincronizarPause() {
  audio1.pause();
  audio2.pause();
}

var audio1 = document.createElement("audio");
audio1.setAttribute("src", "http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-128k.ogg");
audio1.setAttribute("controls", "controls");

var audio2 = document.createElement("audio");
audio2.setAttribute("src", "http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/a2002011001-e02-128k.ogg");
audio2.setAttribute("controls", "controls");

var tiempo1 = document.getElementById('t1');
var tiempo2 = document.getElementById('t2');
var diferencia = document.getElementById('d');

audio1.addEventListener("timeupdate",function(){
        tiempo1.value = this.currentTime;
        diferencia.value = Math.abs(this.currentTime-audio2.currentTime);
});
audio2.addEventListener("timeupdate",function(){
        tiempo2.value = this.currentTime;
        diferencia.value = Math.abs(this.currentTime-audio1.currentTime);
});

audio1.oncanplaythrough = sincronizarAudio;
audio1.onplay = sincronizarPlay;
audio1.onpause = sincronizarPause;
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(audio1);
audio2.oncanplaythrough = sincronizarAudio;
audio2.onplay = sincronizarPlay;
audio2.onpause = sincronizarPause;
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(audio2);
```

```html
<div>
  Tiempo audio 1: <input type=text id=t1>
</div>
<div>
  Tiempo audio 1: <input type=text id=t2>
</div>
<div>
  Diferencia: <input type=text id=d>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace mucho que no trabajo con audio, pero recuerdo que la manera de conseguir esto era con ***buffers* de audio**, de lo contrario verás que a medida que los sonidos se reproducen se irán descuadrando poco a poco.

Trabajar con audio puede ser en muchos casos una tarea compleja, más aún si no se tiene una idea de como funciona el sonido (como es mi caso). Te recomiendo que te mires [este artículo](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/) de **html5rocks** en el que explican bastante bien como trabajar con audio en HTML5/JS y si no recuerdo mal hay un ejemplo que te valdría para lo que necesitas.